# ¿Existe un metodo en el cual pueda transformar de + a %20 en una URL para enviar datos a un servidor desde Java?

Tags: java

Me encuentro trabajando en un proyecto en el cual debo de enviar datos por URL desde java, el caso es que al momento de enviarlos por esta linea de codigo:

`String stringEncoded = URLEncoder.encode("Hola Mundo", "UTF-8");`

El resultado es: ***Hola+Mundo***

y lo que deseo obtener es: ***Hola%20Mundo***

Para que de esta forma se pueda enviar así: `http://ip/folder/index.php?nombre=Hola%20Mundo`

Gracias!

Comment: ¿Por qué quieres hacer eso? Generalmente es mejor enviar las URL codificada. Cuando la muestras en el servidor o la usas para una consulta, por lo general decodificas el valor si hace falta allí al recbirlo. Y si es para una consulta SQL funciona sin ningún problema.

Comment: Es valido usar + para los espacios.

Comment: Pregunta similar en inglés: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding-of-query-string-parameters

Answer (score 2):

En realidad no es un problema al codificar la url de la forma como lo realizas:

```
String stringEncoded = URLEncoder.encode("Hola Mundo", StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

y **obtener `Hola+Mundo`, es completamente valido y no debe causar ningun problema**.

el espacio representado por `%20` es usado para representar espacios en una URI.

---

Si deseas obtener el formato con  `%20` en lugar de `+` puedes realizarlo precisamente convirtiendo la url a URI:

```
 try {
        String urlString = "http://ip/folder/index.php?nombre=Hola Mundo";            
        URL url= new URL(urlString);
        URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), IDN.toASCII(url.getHost()), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
        String correctEncodedURL = uri.toASCIIString();
        System.out.println(correctEncodedURL);

    } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Para obtener como salida:

```
http://ip/folder/index.php?nombre=Hola%20Mundo
```